# Infinite scroll does not work properly with large data

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scrollbar

We have used react-custom-scrollbars component and implemented infinite scrollbar by calling apis with pagination support.

We have used the grid layout and rendered inside the react-custom-scrollbars.

The component works fine with some amount of data, but after a large amount of data, the component shows weird output. **After scrolling a lot at a certain point all the data gets overlapped into one grid span and does not get appended to a new row.**

**Image 1**: All the data after a certain time got overlapped on the span and not worked as was expected.

**Image 2**: On inspection in browser it shows message ***"Show all Nodes"*** as you can see in the other image attached.

The data to be rendered is created in jsx and stored in the local state of the component.

**Image 1**: The image showing the overlapped data.

[image: The image showing unexpected behaviour]

**Image 2**: The image showing show all nodes inside inspect of browser

[image: Show all nodes can be seen in the]

Please if anyone can suggest what's actually happening here and how can I solve this issue.